# Cant able to call Async Task

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

> I have an issue of calling AsyncTask.I am calling AsyncTask inside
>   button but its not going for do in background and onPost execute.
>   After clicking button nothing happens. Please help me to rectify
>   mistake.

**Photo.class**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View takephoto_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, null,false);
    img_profile = (ImageView)takephoto_view.findViewById(R.id.profile_imgphoto);
    but_takephoto = (Button)takephoto_view.findViewById(R.id.profile_buttakephoto);
    but_savephoto = (Button)takephoto_view.findViewById(R.id.profile_butsavephoto);
    but_takephoto.setOnClickListener(listener_takephoto);
    but_savephoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            firstmethod();
        }
    });

    return takephoto_view;
}


public void firstmethod() {
    new MyAsyn(getActivity()).execute();
}

public class MyAsyn extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    Context con;

    public MyAsyn(Context con) {
        this.con = con;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
//          HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
//         
//
//          StringBuilder sb;
//          try {
//              
//              StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
//             
//              httppost.setEntity(se);
//              System.out.print(json);
//              HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
//              if(response != null)
//              {
//                  InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
//   
//                  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
//                  sb = new StringBuilder();
//   
//                  String line = null;
//                  try {
//                      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
//                          sb.append(line + "\n");
//                          
//                      }
//                      
//                      
//                  } catch (IOException e)
//                  {
//                      e.printStackTrace();
//                  } 
//                  finally {
//                      try {
//                          is.close();
//                      } catch (IOException e) {
//                          e.printStackTrace();
//                      }
//                  }
//                  
//                  
//                  
//                 
//              }
//   
//              
//          }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          } catch (IOException e) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          }
            return null;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: What's in the logcat ?

Comment: @LittleChild: No error it shows but after some time its going to AsyncTask. I do no why its taking some time to enter

Comment: What happens if you set breakpoints? FWIW, I never call the `super` in AsyncTasks, but that shouldn't break it.

Comment: @Giridharan hmm.. that is after uncommenting your code?

Comment: @323go:when i set break points after some time delay of time its entering into AsyncTask . I dont know why it happens

Comment: How long is the delay? Are you on device or in emulator?

Comment: @323go: in device only.. It takes about 3 to 4 min and some time above. i cant able to identify when it occurs

Comment: Do you have other AyncTasks elsewhere in the code? AsyncTasks are, by default, executed serially now, so if you have one long-running AsyncTask elsewhere, then this task will not be executed until after the first one (and all other previous ones) has completed.

Comment: are u running any other async task apart prior to this one ?

Comment: no i am not running any other tasks. i am using only onActivityResult for photo and some times only Async thread is executing and some times it doesnt runs . I am using AsynTask inside Fragment..

Comment: For grins and giggles, try to `executeOnExecutor` on this one, just to eliminate any other Async'ness (possibly from third party tools).

Comment: @323go: how to do it can u help me?

Comment: by the way `onActivityResult` sometimes doesn't work inside a fragment because when u start the camera your activity goes to background and if the device memory is low the android might choose to kill your activity. In this case you wont get the result inside `onActivityResult`

Comment: @Deb: i am not calling inside AsyncTask am just testing the task inside a button listener.. but it doesnot invoke it.. i do no what problem is this

Comment: Instead of `execute()` use `executeOnExecutor( THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR )`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for Async task In Android:

To call Async Task Use this from any method:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key1", "value1"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key1", "value2"));
    new WEBSERVICEREQUESTOR(URL, params).execute();
```

Make this as member of class :

```
class WEBSERVICEREQUESTOR extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{

    String URL;
    List<NameValuePair> parameters;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    public WEBSERVICEREQUESTOR(String url, List<NameValuePair> params)
    {
        this.URL = url;
        this.parameters = params;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Processing Request...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try
        {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

            if (parameters != null)
            {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
            }
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            return EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        }  catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        pDialog.dismiss();

        try
        {

        } catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```